# Check if data coming continuously

Tags: powershell, filesystems, directory

Every hour data comes into every folder of my dir tree. I need to check if it does come in every hour, or of there was any interruption. (For example, no data coming in for 2–3 hours.)

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will check `LastWriteTime` for every folder, but it would solve the problem with gaps. If I would check the logs in the morning I would see that all is OK if some data come to folder one hour ago, but was not there a few hours earlier.

So IMHO `LastWriteTime` is not suitable for it.

Also there is a problem with subfolders. I need to check only the last folder in every dir tree. I do not know how to drop any previous folders like:

```
Z:\temp #need to drop
Z:\temp\foo #need to drop
Z:\temp\foo\1 #need to check
```

I had tried to write a script that checks the `LastAccessTime`, but it throws an error:

> Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.

The script is as follows:

```
$rootdir = "Z:\SatData\SatImages\nonprojected\"
$timedec1 = (Get-date).AddHours(-1)
$timedec2 = (Get-date).AddHours(-2)
$timedec3 = (Get-date).AddHours(-3)
$timedec4 = (Get-date).AddHours(-4)


$dir1 = get-childitem $rootdir –recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object FullName | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -lt $timedec1} | $_.LastWriteTime -gt $timedec4 -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timedec3

$dir1
```

But as I said before it does not solve the problem.

--
The main question exactly about checking of continuously data collections. I would make dir tree bu hands, but I need to way to check if data had come to folder every hour or there was any hours without data...

Answer (score 0):

you can try to setup the powershell script to run in a Windows Scheduler (which will run every hour). This way, the script  will only have to check if any data arrived within the past one hour.